# How can I use a DOS .bat to insert line with a calculated value into an XML file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to use a DOS batch file to add a line with a computed value to an xml file.

This my input:

```
<Sale>
  <saleID>82</saleID>
  <total currency="USD" readonly="true">63</total>
  <cost currency="USD" readonly="true">38.54</cost>
</Sale>
```

Calculate 'profit' as (total-cost) and generate this:

```
<Sale>
  <saleID>82</saleID>
  <total currency="USD" readonly="true">63</total>
  <cost currency="USD" readonly="true">38.54</cost>
  <profit>24.46</profit>
</Sale>
```

Tried xmlstarlet but it didn't have the math functions needed. Any suggestions for how to do this with a .bat?

Thanks!

Comment: .bat isn't exactly the easiest environment for doing text manipulation in. good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem will be that the `<` and `>` symbols are litterly everywhere in an XML file. (HTML too).

In batch, those are redirection characters, and will cause errors in every line that deals with text containing them, unless handled very carefully. Possibly even then.

What needs to happen is that these get replaced by something else. Either the batch escape character `^` + the symbol, or by something else entirely.  The problem with escaping them, is that each time that string is exposed to a batch command, the escape character will go away.

So let's say that you escape all the redirection symbols.

The next time you change that string, the escape characters will work by escaping the redirection symbols, but in doing so they are "used up" and dissapear from the string.  Meaning the very next time you do **anything** to that string, they won't be there, and an error will occur because you're redirecting nothing to nothing. Or something to nothing, or.... etc.

You can get around that by using surrounding the string with double quotes, but using double quotes introduces it's own set of problems, and those vary depending on HOW you use those double quotes. Do you put them inside the string? Around the string? Or do you surround your commands with them. Every technique has it's drawbacks and limitations. One of them being that you cannot combine two of those techniques, let alone all thee.

Lastly, to actually INSERT a line into the middle of a file, (anywhere but the end, in fact) you'll need to create a **new** file, and add the line to that when you get to the proper point in it.  Which means that ALL the changes that you made to the line of data, needs to be **reversed**, then the redirection characters escaped (because surrounding the string with double quotes will merely confuse your XML parser). Making simple elimination of bothersome characters simply not an option.

The meat of you're batch would be something like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set source=c:\whatever.xml
set dest=c:\temp.xml

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (%source%) do (
   :: One technique for dealing with redirection characters
   set "line=%%x"
   make_line_palitable_to_batch
   if (line_contains_flag) (
     do_calculation_or_manipulation
     echo restored_!line!>>%dest%
   )
   echo restored_!line!>>%dest%
)
move /y %dest% %source%
```

It's those little lines of pseudo code `make_line_palitable_to_batch` and `restored_!line!` that will kill you.

One of the characters that need replaced is

```
"
```

If you work on replacing that character, recognizing what lines contain data you need, and where to insert the new data, I'll supply the code for replacing the redirection characters and fix your code if needed. (Keep in mind that replacing a double-quote **can** be tricky, but that the most basic method of search and replace will work.)

After you've done this, **edit your question to contain your work**.
Also, you don't have to be perfect, just show some effort and I'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this. I think I will bite the bullet and teach myself how to do it with VBscript.